# How to change the internal trace location for nunit console?

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I've used `--trace=Verbose` for my nunit-console application, and I observe that trace log are created at the current directory where I call the nunit-console from the command line.

But is there anyway to set-- as a command line parameter-- the directory for which the trace log is created? In that way I can better control the trace log location in my batch script, instead of having it depending on the current directory.